# Google Analytics custom report

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a custom report in google analytics which should have following structure.

```
Date(Yesterday)                 |    Revenue       |       Sessions

 - Safari
 - Chrome
 - Firefox

Date(Day before Yesterday)

 - Safari
 - Chrome
 - Firefox
```

I need this data basically to compare Revenue and Session for each of the browser type for past 2 days. So basically Date(Yesterday) dimension up top of the and under that all the browsers and their revenue and sessions, then comes another Date(Day before yesterday) and all the browsers date for this particular date.

I have been able to get the data I need but not the structure, any ideas please?

[image]

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question

Comment: Sorry @Max what I need is browsers data to be compared by date. Past 2 days to be precise. I am adding more details in the question. Just a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no dimension `yesterday` or `before yesterday` in GA. You need to export the report to Excel to create structure exactly as you need.

May be this structure will be good for you:
dimension `browser`, metrics `revenue` and `sessions` and comparison via date range:

[image]

**Idea №2**

Create 2 tabs in report with filter for each of dates.

Comment: Thank you! for your answer, I totally get that. I can use Date dimension for sure, Yesterday and Day before yesterday here are just used for the sake of simplicity, I need all the browsers to be grouped under a particular date and then all the metrics for each of these browser for that date.

Comment: @Ms. Easy's answer should give you that. If just clones the report in 2 (1 for each period) and compares both periods across all dimensions/metrics. If the issue is the visualization of GA which is not the way you want, you can try other solutions like Google Data Studio or Google Sheets to make it look the way you like, but as far as getting the data from the GA UI, that's pretty much it.